# Replace a vector's content without recycling?

Tags: r, vector, replace

Consider the following Python

```
l = list(range(9))
print(l[3:6]) #[3, 4, 5]
l[3:6] = [100]
print(l) #[0, 1, 2, 100, 6, 7, 8]
```

Notice that one element is replaced and the other two in `l[3:6]` are removed. The best equivalent R that I've managed is

```
l <- 0:8
print(l[4:6]) #c(3, 4, 5)
l[4] <- 100
l <- l[-c(5,6)]
print(l) #c(0, 1, 2, 100, 6, 7, 8)
```

and that annoys me very much.

Is there any way to simultaneously replace and remove items from an R vector, like in the Python example? Or, to put it another way, can multiple elements of an R vector be replaced by a shorter vector?

Comment: The best I'm aware of atm is `c(l[1:3], 100, l[7:9])`

Comment: replacement _changes the length_ of an object? and they say r's internals are bad...

Comment: python also supports a vector on the lhs of assignment (e.g., `ret1, ret2 = funcall(...)`), which I really like, and while there's a 3rd-party package (_somewhere_) that supports it for R, it has not caught on in the mainstream. I'm not totally opposed to changing the length on replacement, I think that kind of behavior is fine as long as the side-effect is well known/documented.

Comment: (that behavior would clearly _break_ things like `data.frame` column-reassignment, but if you're using that length-changing effect then it might be safe to assume you aren't using that struct.)

Comment: @r2evans so in python where does 100 go: `l[-c(1, 4, 6)] <- 100`

Comment: @rawr, that's not _quite_ the right syntax, I don't think python allows arbitrary index replacement like that; for instance, python's `l[3:6]` is akin to R's `l[3:5]`, but R's `l[c(1,4,6)]` has no LHS equivalent in python, instead one needs _"comprehensions"_, ala `[ l[i] for i in [1,4,6] ]`, which does not work on the LHS of assignment.

Comment: good point, thanks @onyambu, I'm not fluent enough to know that off the top of my head, _thank you!_

Comment: @rawr using numpy you can use logical indices to replace the values: eg `l[~np.in1d(np.indices(l.shape), np.r_[0,3,5])] = 100` to indicate positions other than `0, 3, 5`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *hack*:

```r
fun <- function(x, i, val = NULL) {
  force(val)
  x <- x[-i]
  c(x[seq_len(min(i)-1)], val, x[-seq_len(min(i)-1)])
}
fun(l, 4:6)
# [1] 0 1 2 6 7 8
fun(l, 4:6, 100)
# [1]   0   1   2 100   6   7   8
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering python manages lists not vectors, you can use this perhaps more intuitive approach:

```r
l <- 0:8
l |> as.list() |> replace(4:6, NULL) |> append(100, after=3) |> unlist()
#> [1]   0   1   2 100   6   7   8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate the same in R by just creating a class that does what you want. Simply put, you need at least 4 simple functions, and then you can make your vector behave the way you want:

```
py_class <- function(x)structure(x, class = c('py_class', class(x)))
print.py_class <- function(x,...) cat(' [', toString(x), ']\n', sep='')
"[.py_class" <- function(x, index) py_class(NextMethod())

#Main function to do the job you need
`[<-.py_class` <- function(x, index, value){
  if(length(index) > 1 & length(value) == 1) {
    x <- x[-index[-1]]
    index <- index[1]
  }
  NextMethod()
}

l <- py_class(0:8)
l[2:5] <- 100
l
[0, 100, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Notice that the function replaces the values in positions 2:5 in R. Can we make it resemble the python code of taking integers from 0 instead of 1? Yes of course, we would need to tweak the functions above in the necessary manner.

One thing you need to note is that these are basic syntax of a language and if you are trying to replicate one in the other, then you better stick to the one you prefer. Otherwise you have to accept the differences and try to find ways of solving the problem at hand without replicating the code of the other.